# Laravel only saves first item to database why?

Tags: php, laravel

```
    public function download****()
    {
        // Downloads new externals (if updateable)
        $site_id = 1;
        $sinceLastId = $this->lastExternalSiteOrderId($site_id);
        $api_version = config('services.*****.api_version');
        $path = '/admin/api/' . $api_version . '/orders.json';

        // GET request - Shopify.php (orders.json)
        $result = $this->basicShopifyApi*****()->rest('GET', $path, ['since_id' => $sinceLastId]);
        $orders = $result->body->orders;

        if (!isset($orders)) {
            return Response::json(['message' => 'No new ***** orders to download!'], 204);
        } else {
            foreach ($orders as $order) {
                // Save to External Log
                ExternalLog::create([
                    'data' => $order,
                ]);

                // Gets updatable status
                $updatable = $this->updateable($order->id);

                // Saves new externals (create), if updateable
                if ($updatable) {
                    $this->updateOrCreateExternals($order, $site_id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
  // Updates a external role
    public function updateOrCreateExternals($request, $site_id) {

        // Saves external updates
        $external = External::updateOrCreate(
            [
                'site_order_id' => ['order_id' => $request->id],
                'site_id' => $site_id],
            [
//                    'order_id' => 0, // not required
                'site_order_id' => $request->id,
                'site_id' => $site_id, // Shopify is 1 (within ShopifyController this is correct)
                'site_sub_id' => 0,
                'site_account_id' => 0,
                'data' => $request,
                'site_order_status' => 0,
                'order_created_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($request->created_at)),
                'order_updated_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($request->updated_at)),
            ]);

        echo "ShopifyExternalController@updateOrCreate function called!";

        // Creates Customers, Orders, Carts, Payments for external, then set Site_Order_Status to 10
        $shopifyOrderController = new shopifyOrderController();
        $shopifyOrderController->updateOrCreateOrders($site_id);
    }
```

This code works locally, but on dev (staging) server it only saves the first item?

Any ideas, why it won't work on the server?

It is shared hosting, cent os, PHP 7.2, not set up with Laravel Forge or vapor.

Any tips on writing YAML scripts to deploy a site correctly?

I have tried doing "composer dump-autoload" as I recently changed some of the controller names from lowercase to uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

```
updateOrCreate
```

Updates only one model rather than many .

Comment: Incorrect, it is called by another function... That is not the problem.

It does not work on remote server but works locally.